# Which class should I place this method in? C++

Tags: c++, class, object, inheritance, implementation

I'm making a Rogue Like game based off of Nethack. I need to decide the best class to place the methods for navigating through the dungeon. Right now the way I'm implementing moving is by simply asking the **Player** for a char input. (using W,A,S,D as arrows). I have a while set up so it loops through until a trigger char ends the program.. In this loop it starts off by printing the state of the dungeon. The char input is asked for, followed by if statements to check which character is entered. In each of these if statements, it will call a method relative to the input/direction wanting to move. So I'll have: moveUp(), moveRight(), and so on.. I just need to figure out which class would be best to put these methods in, which will determine how the methods are called, what to pass, and so on.

I'll list the classes in bold and represent the inheritance with indentations. Here are my classes involved:

- **Entity**: The base class. It essentially represents any/all of the objects

  - **Creature**: Basically represents a living "thing" in the dungeon

    - **Player**: Basically an extended Creature.. It's the class for who's playing.
  - **Item**: Acts as a base class for anything that's considered an Item

    - **Weapon**: A weapon..
    - **Armor**: A piece of armor..
    - **Consumable**: An Item that can be consumed.. Has several other classes

I also have a few Independent classes:

- **Tile**: A space on the "gameboard." It holds a ptr to Creature, vector of pointers to Items, and a char that displays what that space represents.
- **DungeonLevel**: This is the gameboard/grid for a single level. It has a 2D vector of **Tile** objects.

I already have the dungeon generating properly and what not. For each **DungeonLevel** object, all of the **Tiles** will stay in the same spot. So when a **Player** or **Creature** move (1 spot) the program will call these methods to manipulate the **DungeonLevel** object (the 2D vector of **Tile's**) to reflect where the Player/Creatures moved to by passing them from Tile to Tile. Then the program restarts the loop.

I'm not sure which class to put these methods in. I essentially need the Creatures and Player to be able to move. And the Player moves based on a char input. The Creatures/Monsters generated in the game will be moving 1 space towards the Player (if possible).

So I'm not sure if I should use the same methods to control any **Entity** or if the **DungeonLevel** should control movement, or the Creature base class and derived, Player, classes should have the same movement methods, or if Creature should have its own and Player should have its own.

Suggestions? Thanks.

Comment: This is not an answer to your question, but based on the kinds of decisions you are making I highly recommend getting a book on design patterns if you do not already have one. I have Design Patterns: Elements of Reusable Object-Oriented Software and recommend it. This book is opening my mind to different ways of designing classes and interactions between classes.

Comment: Yeah that's a good idea. Thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: There's a c++ tutorial for programming roguelike games using the libtcod library at http://codeumbra.eu/complete-roguelike-tutorial-using-c-and-libtcod-part-1-setting-up, which has a fairly well-thought out class heirarchy. The c++ tutorial is based on the more complete python tutorial at http://roguebasin.roguelikedevelopment.org/index.php?title=Complete_Roguelike_Tutorial,_using_python%2Blibtcod (which I have had some involvement in).

Answer (score 1):

since you are doing a 2d game. im presuming you are using opengl. or directx.

for moving the tiles of the dungeon. i would suggest you dont move them. but instead move the "camera" there are many books for opengl and directx for how rending works. that way all you need to do. is check which tiles are on screen or not and only draw the ones onscreen.

as for deciding who should control what. it would be logical that Player control's he's own movememnt. but has functions to allow external classes to move him. do not allow direct access to he's privates because they are not friends  ;).

now for how your classes should be laid out. its hard to definitively answer that. but from what is presented.

look at it like this, player and creature and items all inherit from entity. what do they all need to have in common? they all need a position. functions to be able to get and set their positions. their rotation. maybe a name to identify them. and an update function to handle any actions that occur to them? this is where virtual functions come in handy.

because you could have `virtual void Update(int a_iDeltaTime);`
in your base class. and everythign that inherits from it has its own type of update. i.e player checks keypresses. while enemy's only update their rotation and movement.

EDIT: that way you can just store all ur enemy's players items. as entity*'s and when you call update because its virtual. it will call the proper update based on what type it really is. which means you only need 1 list to store every type of entity in the game. END.

that way you put all that stuff that is shared between them all in the base class. and only put the unique stuff in the main classes.

everything i have said is simply sugggestions as your implementation should be whats best suited to the exact problems you face. and the only way you get better at knowing what implementaitons to use where is by practice and as mentioned eariler you should definetly learn more about design patterns as it will open your mind to ways to code things. and allow you to write simplier easier to read code. hope this helps.

Comment: Roguelikes are, traditionally, *text-based*, and run in a standard terminal, using either standard `conio` functions, or support lib like `curses`